# How to manipulate python dataframe for indexing and/or pivoting for two columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

Note: The code for the following can be found on my [github repository](https://github.com/ecmyhre/customer-switching/blob/master/customer_switching.ipynb).

I have python dataframe that I am attempting to index in such a way that will allow me to examine the customers in the dataset, `user_id`, and their subscriptions, `id`, to then perform basic time series analysis.

I've tried creating pivot tables and various indexing, but I can't get it to work. How do I manipulate the df to allow me to search and segment based on `user_id`(customer) that have just one `id`(subscription) associated with them and `user_id`(customer) that have more than one `id`(subscription)? Or is there a way to write a function to do this?

1. groupby:
   `data1.groupby('user_id').groups`

output:

```
Int64Index([1507701], dtype='int64', name='id'),
 5404: Int64Index([1526753], dtype='int64', name='id'),
 7938: Int64Index([1489315], dtype='int64', name='id'),
 17951: Int64Index([1526391, 2050396, 2050416, 2050417, 2050418], dtype='int64', name='id'),
 19323: Int64Index([1447565, 1482407], dtype='int64', name='id'),
 19468: Int64Index([1490024], dtype='int64', name='id'),
 20407: Int64Index([1524039], dtype='int64', name='id'),
 30813: Int64Index([1537149], dtype='int64', name='id'),
 32786: Int64Index([1529058, 1529059, 1714909], dtype='int64', name='id'),
 33316: Int64Index([1528798], dtype='int64', name='id'),
 36867: Int64Index([1493735], dtype='int64', name='id'),
 42060: Int64Index([1607724], dtype='int64', name='id'),
 44155: Int64Index([1473383, 1474035, 1547023], dtype='int64', name='id'),
 49526: Int64Index([1493405], dtype='int64', name='id'),
```

The above seems to be along the track of what I am trying to accomplish(eg, `17951: Int64Index([1526391, 2050396, 2050416, 2050417, 2050418], dtype='int64', name='id'),` shows a `user_id` with multiple `id`'s)

But how do I perform this on the dataframe itself? Or continue with this to then work with this? I'm not sure exactly how to word this, sorry :/

Comment: Please publish the discussed code here, so people willing to help you will not have to leave the site - their personal time matters.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Creates table with each customer having a row for each unique subscription id
cust_sub_table = df.drop_duplicates(['user_id', 'id'])[['user_id', 'id']]

# Get number of subscriptions per customer
cust_sub_count = cust_sub_table.groupby(['user_id']).count().reset_index()

# Get customers with only one subscription
one_sub_cust = cust_sub_count.query('id == 1')
```